# Any idea to prevent specific attribute to appear in the logs?

Tags: java, sonarqube, slf4j

I'm looking for a way to prevent some sensitive data from being logged.

Ideally i would like to prevent / capture things like

```
String sensitive = "";
log.info ("This should be prevented or caught by something : {} ", sensitive);
```

this post is a bit of a longshot, I'm willing to investigate on any lead.
annotation, new types, Sonar Rules, logger hacking etc...

thx for your brainstorming :)

guillaume

Comment: You must filter the output from your chosen backend. To my knowledge this is not standard functionality.

Comment: Which logging backend are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create custom type for it.

Make sure that `toString` doesn't return actual content.

Comment: ended up doing that, not that painful that one could expect.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine there are multiple ways to do this, but one way is to use the Logback configuration file, to specify a message provider for the "arguments" and "message".  In those providers, you define a "writeTo" method that looks for particular patterns in the output, and masks them.

This is the path to a solution, but I obviously don't provide many details here. I'm not aware of any "standard" solutions for this.

Another possibility would avail itself if your architecture has services running in transient containers, and the log output is sent to a centralized log aggregator, like Splunk.  If you were ok with the initial logs written in the container having sensitive data, you could have the log aggregator look for patterns to mask for.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend two options, can you split your PII data into a separate log  and then log that data securely?

If not, consider something like Cribl Logstream. Point your log shipper at it and let it strip away any PII you are concerned about. LogStream makes it very very easy to remove/mask/encrypt sensitive data. It has all sorts of other features as well.

At my last job we used LogStream as the router to make decisions about the data based on the content. PII data was detected and one copy was pushed to a secure PII certified logging platform and another copy was pushed to the operational logging platform but the PII data was masked so a wider audience could use the logging with no risk. It was a very useful workflow that solved a log of problems.